# I don't know how to connect preconfigured OpenWRT router to my home network

Tags: openwrt

What I need to do is to connect preconfigured OpenWRT router to another network through WAN cable connection.

My router assign the IP address to new router but even if I use this address it still rejects my SSL connection (as it appears).

I've done some googling and read some OpenWRT wiki pages but then I found out that I am missing directories such as '/etc/config'.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm confused, its preconfigured as in someone else set it up for you? In which case, didn't they tell you? (I've done this for people with Linux boxes, and I give them instructions—preferably simple, like "plug the ethernet cable in here.") Or do you mean it came with OpenWRT pre-installed (but not configured)?

Comment: @derpbert, I got this router from school to practice few things. I know how to connect it through cable to PC but when I tried to plugin cable from my home router LANs to OpenWRT WAN jack it won't let me connect. It gets my homes local IP address but is still unaccessible. Why?

Comment: It was pre-installed and pre-configured I suppose, but not working :(

Comment: Well, it sounds like when you connect it to the PC, you're accessing it from its LAN ports, but when you connect it to your home network, you're trying to access it from its WAN port. Maybe administration via WAN is disabled/firewalled? [Guessing here, I haven't ever used OpenWRT]

Comment: BTW, once you type start typing a @-reply, you can tab-complete the nickname. I suggest this because I notice you spelled mine wrong (but thankfully the site notified me anyway...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File in /etc/ directory called firewall.user must be modified to allow port 22 to connect the router.

Answer (score 2):

@derobert is correct.

It is unaccessable because by default you cannot access the management web-page from the WAN interface. Only trusted devices (inside LAN) should be able to access the management interface.

Comment: Do you know how to configure firewall in my case?

Comment: in the Administration section there is an option to enable management from WAN via http(s)/telnet/ssh/etc